# slurm SBATCH - Multiple Nodes, Same SLURMD_NODENAME

Tags: linux, bash, hpc, slurm

- slurm-wlm 17.11.2
- Installed from Ubuntu Apt repos, Ubuntu:18.04

We have a cluster of 20 identical nodes.
Running the simple script below give me a confusing problem.
All the jobs think they are running on node3, while running the hostname command gives the accurate answer. This is also a problem for the output filename. I expected to have many different outputs, but I get just one, with 'node3' in the filename. This seems to be a Bash Eval() / Variable substitution error.
Wrapping

```
SLURMD_NODENAME
```

in a

```
bash -c "echo Bash3: \$SLURMD_NODENAME"
```

works. But why did I have to do this?

cn.job:

```
#!/bin/bash
#SBATCH --output=/share/output.txt.%j.%J.%a.%A.%n.%N.%s.%t.%x

#SBATCH --time=00:00:30
#SBATCH --tasks-per-node=2
#SBATCH --nodes=4

srun hostname
srun bash -c "echo Bash2: \$(hostname)"
srun echo SLURMD_NODENAME:$SLURMD_NODENAME SLURM_ARRAY_TASK_ID:$SLURM_ARRAY_TASK_ID SLURM_ARRAY_JOB_ID:$SLURM_ARRAY_JOB_ID SLURM_JOB_ID:$SLURM_JOB_ID SLURM_TASK_PID:$SLURM_TASK_PID
srun bash -c "echo Bash3: \$SLURMD_NODENAME"

srun sleep 20
```

Ran like:

```
sbatch cn.job
```

produces this output:

**/share/output.txt.2056.2056.4294967294.2056.0.node3.4294967294.0.cn.job**

```
node3
node3
node6
node4
node5
node6
node4
node5
Bash2: node3
Bash2: node6
Bash2: node4
Bash2: node5
Bash2: node3
Bash2: node4
Bash2: node6
Bash2: node5
SLURMD_NODENAME:node3 SLURM_ARRAY_TASK_ID: SLURM_ARRAY_JOB_ID: SLURM_JOB_ID:2056 SLURM_TASK_PID:6441
SLURMD_NODENAME:node3 SLURM_ARRAY_TASK_ID: SLURM_ARRAY_JOB_ID: SLURM_JOB_ID:2056 SLURM_TASK_PID:6441
SLURMD_NODENAME:node3 SLURM_ARRAY_TASK_ID: SLURM_ARRAY_JOB_ID: SLURM_JOB_ID:2056 SLURM_TASK_PID:6441
SLURMD_NODENAME:node3 SLURM_ARRAY_TASK_ID: SLURM_ARRAY_JOB_ID: SLURM_JOB_ID:2056 SLURM_TASK_PID:6441
SLURMD_NODENAME:node3 SLURM_ARRAY_TASK_ID: SLURM_ARRAY_JOB_ID: SLURM_JOB_ID:2056 SLURM_TASK_PID:6441
SLURMD_NODENAME:node3 SLURM_ARRAY_TASK_ID: SLURM_ARRAY_JOB_ID: SLURM_JOB_ID:2056 SLURM_TASK_PID:6441
SLURMD_NODENAME:node3 SLURM_ARRAY_TASK_ID: SLURM_ARRAY_JOB_ID: SLURM_JOB_ID:2056 SLURM_TASK_PID:6441
SLURMD_NODENAME:node3 SLURM_ARRAY_TASK_ID: SLURM_ARRAY_JOB_ID: SLURM_JOB_ID:2056 SLURM_TASK_PID:6441
Bash3: node3
Bash3: node5
Bash3: node3
Bash3: node4
Bash3: node6
Bash3: node4
Bash3: node6
Bash3: node5
```

Answer (score 1):

> SLURMD_NODENAME: Name of the node upon which the current job step executes

(from e.g. https://www.nccs.nasa.gov/user_info/slurm/environment_variables/sbatch)

So what happens is that your cn.job file is executed in the context of the allocation but before any job step (the `srun`). There it is executed like a regular bash file so variable substitution kicks in replacing the `$SLURMD_NODENAME` with the value as seen on the machine where your batch script runs on. The result is then executed via srun leading to something like:

`srun echo $SLURMD_NODENAME` -> `srun echo node3`

The other commands all prevent expansion of the variable and run the expansion (or hostname command) on the compute nodes in the job step, so they work as expected.

One consider `srun` as a super-charged `ssh`. You will notice that `srun hostname && srun $HOSTNAME` will behave just like `ssh node hostname && ssh node $HOSTNAME` (obviously modulo the parallel execution).

Slight difference for SLURM: SBatch files are executed on a compute node. So you won't get the same output as when you run `srun` on the login node.

For the single-output file: Not sure, but usually all output from a job gets gathered and put to a single sink. That is the stdout for interactive jobs or a single output file for sbatch. Where did you get the placeholders from? I'm only aware of `%j %A %a` for job- and array-job-ids. There it obviously makes sense that only a single output file is created.

Comment: I used every placeholder I could find, for testing purposes, found here:
filename pattern section at the bottom of https://slurm.schedmd.com/sbatch.html

The variable expansion makes sense, I just didn't think slurm would work that way. I seem to get different behaviour with Sbatch arrays, but that's another issue, what I really want is the filename to work. Again, this works with job arrays.

Comment: Interesting. The docu clearly states `This will create a separate IO file per xxx.` Maybe SLURM can't handle the combinatorial combinations of that? Because it would have to create a separate file per array-jobID, node and task (3 dimensions). Did you try to reduce this to e.g. `%N`?. And about the "how it works": Consider `srun` a super-power `ssh`. It works essentially the same (I'll add this to the answer)